# Field of one Protocol Buffers Message as field in another Protocol Buffers Message

Tags: nested, buffer, protocols, message

I am new to Protocol Buffers.I would like to know how to nest the field of one protocol buffers message as a field in another protocol buffers message. Can I do that ?

For example, if I have a protocol buffers message called Employee with employeeId as a field,
I would like to use employeeId as a field in another protocol message, say Manager. How can I make the employeeId of employee message a field in Manager message?

Thanks you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The [Protocol Buffers Language Guide](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto) shows how to do this under **Nested Types** if I understand the question correctly.

I originally thought you meant something like this:

```
message Employee {
   optional string employeeId = 1;
}

message Manager {
   optional string employeeId = 1;
}
```

But I wonder if you meant something more like this:

```
message EmpId {
   optional string id = 1;
}

message Employee {
   optional EmpId employeeId = 1;
}

message Manager {
   optional EmpId employeeId = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for you answer. I meant more like your second code snippet. If EmpId has more than one field, say, `message EmpId { required string id = 1; required string name = 2; }` the way I access EmpId.id in Manager is same ? I mean, can I define Manager as `message Manager { required EmpId employeeId = 1; required string managerId = 2; }` Is this correct ?

Comment: Let me make it more clear. I am trying to make only a field of one message as a field in another message. I dont want to make a whole message as another field in another message. Hope, this clarifies my question.